# Loading CascadeClassifier xml file in OpenCV 2.4.7

Tags: visual-c++, opencv

I have many weird problems with OpenCV 2.4.7. This time I can not load cascade files, I tried these:

```
1. face_cascade.load("d:/haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml")



2. FileStorage fs("d:/haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml", FileStorage::READ);
    if (!fs.isOpened())
    {
        cout<<"can not read xml"<<endl;
    }
```

None of the above codes work. I tried to read file as:

```
FILE *in = fopen("d:/haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml", "r");
char buff[200];
fscanf(in, "%s", buff);
cout<<buff<<endl;
```

It works, it means I have no problem with file permissions.

What can I do? I just wanted to try tutorial codes, but so far I have so many problems.

I am running Windows 7 x64, visual c++ 2010, visual studio 2008, opencv 2.4.7

Comment: Could you try with VS 2010 and let me know how it works out?

Comment: Could you debug into the OpenCV's code and look up which statement cause the failure?

Comment: @scap3y It worked without any problems in VS 2010. Thanks man